# Error running Spacy-llm with Llama 2 on local computer

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, llama

I’m trying to test spacy-llm (llama 2) NER on my local laptop

My laptop has two GPUs Nividia and Intel

CuPy-cuda112 is installed I run the nvcc –version command and the following is the output:

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67 Build
> cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0

I created the following config file: config.cfg

```
[system] seed = 0 gpu_allocator = "pytorch"

[nlp] lang = "en" pipeline = ["llm"]

[components]

[components.llm] factory = "llm"

[components.llm.task] @llm_tasks = "spacy.NER.v2" labels = ["DISH", "INGREDIENT", "EQUIPMENT", "NAME"]

[components.llm.model] @llm_models = "spacy.Llama2.v1" name = "Llama-2-7b-hf"
```

I have simple demo file: demo.py

```
import spacy from spacy_llm.util 
import assemble from dotenv 
import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

nlp = assemble("config.cfg")

doc = nlp("I know of great pizza recipe with anchovis. Fantahun is responsible for this.") 
print(doc) 
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent, ent.label_)
```

Running the above on my local laptop visual studio code is giving me an error:

> Install CUDA to load and run the LLM on the GPU, or install
> 'accelerate' to dynamically distribute the LLM on the CPU or even the
> hard disk. The latter may be slow.

Where did I make mistake? I assume everything is installed and setup correctly

Comment: If you want to install the GPU-versions of pytorch on Windows, you need to specify a special index https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ (Not sure, but this might at least be a reason.)

Comment: Thank you for your response @pux - but the problem persists after I installed pytorch locally as well